# How do I determine the underlying type of an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the Array Item Type from Array Type in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129831/how-do-i-get-the-array-item-type-from-array-type-in-net)

If I have an array of a particular type is there a way to tell what exactly that type is?

```
 var arr = new []{ "string1", "string2" };
 var t = arr.GetType();
 t.IsArray //Evaluates to true

 //How do I determine it's an array of strings?
 t.ArrayType == typeof(string) //obviously doesn't work
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Type.GetElementType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) - When overridden in a derived class, returns the Type of the object encompassed or referred to by the current array, pointer or reference type.

```
var arr = new []{ "string1", "string2" };
Type type = array.GetType().GetElementType();
```

Answer (score 1):

As your type is known at compile time, you can just check in a C++ way. Like this:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new[] { "s" }; 
        var b = new[] { 1 }; 
        Console.WriteLine(IsStringArray(a));
        Console.WriteLine(IsStringArray(b));
    }
    static bool IsStringArray<T>(T[] t)
    {
        return typeof(T) == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

(produces `True`, `False`)