# How to get the Type of an Array of Nullable Primitive?

Tags: c#, arrays, primitive, underlyingtype

I have a property defined as:

```
public bool[] _array { get; set; }                  
public bool?[] _null_array { get; set; }
```

I followed the instructions in [How do I determine the underlying type of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347053/how-do-i-determine-the-underlying-type-of-an-array)

```
foreach (var _property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
{ 
    var _propertyType = _property.PropertyType;
    var _propertyName = _property.Name;

    var CheckArray = _propertyType.IsArray;
    var UType      = _propertyType.GetElementType().Name;
    ....
}
```

The results for UType is:

```
_array      => "Boolean"
_null_array => "Nullable`1"
```

How do I get the type of an array of nullable primitive ?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by underlying type of an array of nullable primitive?

Comment: @viveknuna eg. int[].... underlying type = int.   
I've removed underlying from the question.  I think I might have mixed up with List<int>... i was referring the link and it mentioned underlying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have it. The array element type is `bool?` aka `Nullable<bool>` aka ``` Nullable``1 ``` (only one backtick, blame markdown) with generic argument `bool`. If you're after `bool`, then you'll want `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` on the element type; this returns `null` for things that aren't `Nullable<T>`, so consider:

```
var type = _propertyType.GetElementType();
type = Nullable.GetUnderylingType(type) ?? type;
var UType = type.Name;
```

Comment: I've asked a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75110741/how-to-get-the-properties-name-type-and-other-info-from-a-class-gotton-through.  @MarcGravel