# How to get the properties name, type and other info from a class gotton through CSharpCompilation.Create()?

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime-compilation

I've previously asked a question "How to get the Type of an Array of Nullable Primitive?" [How to get the Type of an Array of Nullable Primitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75053789/how-to-get-the-type-of-an-array-of-nullable-primitive/75054143#75054143).

In that question, I have a class in my c# program and I was able to use reflection to find out the properties name/type/array(or not)/nullable(or not).

Now, I want to do the same but the class is read in from a file (and not part of the c# program).  I check online for some codes that I can compile the file using CSharpCompilation.Create() into an assembly.  By trial and error, I manage to print out the name and type.

```
 Assembly a = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
 var _prop = a.GetType("ClassName").GetProperties();

 foreach (var _p in _prop)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(_p.Name);
      Console.WriteLine(_p.GetMethod.ReturnType.Name);
      Console.WriteLine();
 }
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to get the information.  But my problem now is that I cannot find out if the type is an array and/or a nullable type.  In my previous question, I learnt that I can use

```
var type = _propertyType.GetElementType();
type = Nullable.GetUnderylingType(type) ?? type;
var UType = type.Name;
```

to get the nullable.  In my current example, how do I know if the property is an array and/or nullable ?  The package I'm using:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit;
using System.Reflection;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a error message or observed with expected behaviour? Reflection is a valid approach to get information after the compilation with `CSharpCompilation`.

Comment: I'm not getting an error.  The above works.  It's just that I don't know how to get the nullable and array info when the class is runtime compiled.  The methods associated with the property looks different.  And if I use Nullable.GetUnderylingType(type), I don't get a type when it's nullable which I did previously.